# Daily ETL job big data files

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I'm using Athena and I'm dealing with about 1000 raw compressed data files daily (each of 13MB). I need to process and store efficiently to improve queries speed and cost and I do it by partitions.

I’m currently using lambdas (being triggered for each file creation) as my ETL and it - loads the raw data file, reorganizes columns, changes the file format (to parquet) and then splits it and saves it to multiple files on S3 bucket.
then another lambda starts and creates new partitions for the Athena table:

s3://raw_data/2020/01/01  --> s3://table_name/2020/01/01/0-50/ (Athena table built over these files)

Many partitions affects on the queries speed, so I've heard of a
new feature called Partitions Projection. using this feature I can speed up the query processing and automate partition management.

I’m a little bit confused of the options.

Another point is that theoretically, if I understand it correctly, I can get rid of the lambdas and save some cost by using Athena **CTAS** once to create the table and then executing **INSERT INTO** daily (limited up to 100 partitions) but then I still use partitions and can't use Partitions Projection.

What is the most efficient way to deal ETL when it comes to daily provided files?

Comment: That's not big data by any definition. It's lots of smallish files which makes handling them a nuisance

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos maybe "big data" term is not correct